# Put ICE on lock screen

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-s-3, lock-screens

Samsung Mega 6.3 SGH-M819N with OS 4.4.2 puts owner's info on the lock screen. How may I replace that with an ICE contact text,  so anyone who finds me Out Of Service can,  without need to unlock the phone,  see who to call for my Emergency contact?

Comment: Using an ICE app, maybe? See: [I.C.E – In Case of Emergency](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/health_ice) for examples.

Comment: Interesting thought, but what's wrong with just typing it in?

Comment: @AaronGillion Nothing. Depends on what you want. Changing the owner info seemed too obvious to me, so I thought OP is after "something more advanced" :)

Comment: @Aaron Gillion,  can't put name + two numbers by selecting  text then the name of next-of-kin and their two numbers, not enough characters allowed.

Comment: @Izzy Checking ICE apps and if you know one which successfully places a widdget on the lock screen, would like to know.

Comment: I'm not using any of those. I like the idea, but somehow doubt its value. "Emergeny staff" (medics) do not check your device (they are even advised against it, privacy and such) – hence my hint to put a note on your insurance card explicitly telling them to check. In which case you also can have those details attached there to save them precious seconds. Not to forget you cannot tell who and when will even check that card: most likely not the ambulance picking you up, but rather some clerk at the hospital later. I'd like to read some "success stories" first :)